# App Store Connect: Creation of apps of this type is not available

Tags: app-store-connect

For the past few weeks, I've been getting an error when trying to create an iOS app in App Store Connect: https://imgur.com/U02cAl2.mp4

- I click <kbd>+</kbd> → <kbd>New App</kbd>
- A progress indicator appears
- The indicator spins forever
- Developer Tools shows that the server returned HTTP `500` and this body:

  ```
  {"data":null,"messages":{"warn":null,"info":null,"error":["Creation of apps of this type is not available"]},"statusCode":"ERROR"}
  ```

#### Troubleshooting

- **Agreeing to terms and conditions**

  - For the error message above, the Google results suggest there are terms and conditions that need to be accepted. I checked both [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com) and [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login), but there are no prompts. My membership page on Apple Developer lists two agreements, both of which have been accepted:

    [image: Both of the two Apple Developer agreements on my membership page are listed as having been accepted]
- **Trying other browsers**

  - Chrome: Same error
  - Firefox: Same error
  - Safari: Same error (https://imgur.com/9bPOY5c.mp4)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Do you have access to a Mac? Can you try this using a recent version of Safari?

Comment: Hi @NimeshNeema, thanks for the warm welcome. I get the same error in Safari—I added a video link.

Comment: iTunes has been having technical difficulties, perhaps this is related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a server error or outage with Apple. You'll need to contact Apple to get the matter resolved, or alternatively wait to see if it resolves itself within few hours.

Comment: I should have mentioned this has been happening for a couple weeks. Edited.

Comment: Still I would advise contacting Apple to resolve this!

Comment: Update: This has been resolved. "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" was missing from https://appstoreconnect.apple.com, but there was an expired agreement that needed review. I opened a ticket on 5/17 and emailed back and forth with Apple until the issue was resolved on 5/31. (The issue was on Apple's end as you thought.) At that point, "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" became available again, and I was able to review and sign the necessary agreements. Then app creation started working.